# What happened to the front of this guitar?

Tags: electric-guitar

It has 4 marks, fairly similar though the two above being smaller than those below, on the front, like it had something attached to it at some point or something - anyone know what it was or how these marks have come about otherwise? And must these have been holes which have been filled in, or is it just cosmetic damage? Many thanks!

(Also feel free to tell me this should be posted on a different site, cheers)

[image][image][image]

Comment: Only a guess - a Roland hexatonic pick up was attached at some time, to go with the Roland synth.

Comment: @Tim that's exactly what it looks like. My Roland hexaphonic pickup has exactly the same footprint.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a Roland hexaphonic pickup, that more often is fitted to Strats, from my experience (I used to own one). It's a special pup that converts to sort of MIDI, and connects via a multi core cable to the Roland 'brain' - a synth, providing every sound one could imagine. Some worked well with this arrangement, some not so. The guitar could still be plugged in via a jack, so the 'best of both worlds'. It never really took off, and fitting was quite finnicky to get the adjustment right.

Seems that could be what's left, as the 'pup' needed to be screwed onto the body, close to the bridge. The other marks are probably from where the socket was fitted.